# How to debug (e.g. print a value in console) in PWA Studio intercept.js (Magento 2.4)

Tags: magento2.4

I want to use console.log to print a variable value inside the local-intercept.js but it compile failed due to dot is not recognized. How can we check variable value for intercept?

```
  const inputComponent = targetables.reactComponent(  
    '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/TextInput/textInput.js'  
  );
  inputComponent.insertAfterSource(
    'TextInput extends Component {',
    '\n\tdefaultClasses = mergeClasses(defaultClasses, customClasses);\n\tconsole.log("defaultClasses is "+defaultClasses);\n'
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, To solve that I **used console.log as you want here, and checked the output in the terminal.**

Once you use console.log in your intercept file, you'll need to **stop terminal and again run yarn watch**

Now when your execution is started, keep eye on the terminal it'll show you log. Checkout bellow images might helpful to you.

local-intercept.js

[image]

terminal output

[image]